# Can Java / Android development be done with a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: java, android

I have several questions closely related to each other. All are pertaining to a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian:

1. Is a recent Java Development Kit (i.e. Java SE 8) available?
2. Is a recent version of the Eclipse IDE (i.e. one supporting Java 8) available?
3. Are there tools available for developing Android Apps? This can be the Android SDK and Eclipse with the ADT plugin or Android Studio.

I do not intend to use the Raspberry for professional development. So I do not mind the system being a bit slow or exposing minor flaws.

By "available" I am meaning in the best case being available for download in binary form from a repository or some other source, but I also have some knowledge in C and C++.

As I have not purchased a Raspberry yet, I cannot find out the answers by trying myself.

Answer (score 1):

I was makind some kind of development on a rpi 3, but it was to slow, now im using that to debug some details, when I want to check if GPIO is working properly.

1,- there is no JAVA SE 8 for RPI, it comes with some JDK for ARM32 architecture, in fact before that JDK comes with JavaFx but now it doesn't

2.- it can work, but if you want to use some jar that is not in the java packages you will have to download them or look for another way to do what u want.
3.- android studio is to heavy to use on RPI
what I suggest is to develop in some common PC and then pass the project to RPI to check details or debug, but not for the whole development, if you want to develop for services with android it simply will crash the RPI, I told u because when I just open 3 tabs of chromium my rpi 3 is freezed.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a good idea. Android SDK has a minimum system requirement of 3 GB of RAM (and recommends 8 GB or more), that alone should prevent it from running properly on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest Raspbian to get Java 1.8 directly.  I have run Intellij successfully on a Raspberry 2, but it really, really likes a faster disk  than the SD-card.  Going in power saving mode helps.

To my understanding the Eclipse 4 series is not immediately available for the Raspberry platform, but Eclipse 3 is available in the package system and works reasonably well especially when working on a faster disk.

I do not know about Android development, but to my understanding Google is building their IDE on IntelliJ.

I would suggest that you buy a cheap older x86 computer instead.  Raspberry is for hobby use where the computer is the target, not the tool.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Currently I use my notebook computer for Android development (at home usually with an external screen, as I prefer a large one for development). I just thought of the Raspberry as an alternative. And relating to the IDE for Android development: Google's "official" IDE Android Studio is indeed built on IntelliJ, but one can also use Eclipse and the Android Development Tool (ADT) plug-in, which is no more updated, but still works (at least when targeting older versions of Android).

Comment: For modern IDE's you want lots of memory and fasts disks.  The money is most likely better spend on maxing out the RAM in your notebook.