# JAVA development environment for Raspberry Pi 2 or perhaps from the command line?

Tags: pi-2, java, software-compilation

Hi I'm new to Raspberry (Pi 2) and would like to know
(1) if it's feasible to develop simple JAVA apps in a development environment (Eclipse? Others?) or failing that from the command line.
(2) a reference to installing whatever the answer is to #1.  I don't have much/any experience installing packages/programs so a tutorial or instructions would be helpful.

I did search the site and came up with:
[Can Java / Android development be done with a Raspberry Pi 3?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71011/can-java-android-development-be-done-with-a-raspberry-pi-3)

However, notice he/she has a pi 3 and also is interested in Android development and possibly complicated applications.  I have much simpler goals.  I just want to (initially at least) program simple console apps for this course: https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1/home/welcome .  Compiling on the command line is an option.
Recent events have suggested to me it's not a good idea to do personal projects on my work computer! And I happen to have a Raspberry Pi 2 kicking around gathering dust.

If you think this is more trouble than it's worth and I should be buying a cheap PC/ChromeBook/Linux system, by all means tell me so. The answer I referenced seems to lean that way. If you have a recommendation for a cheap laptop running some flavor of Linux, even better!

Comment: Running something like eclipse is out of the question, but many/most code editors will have support for java syntax highlighting at least, which is all you really need to start off with.  Search online for "linux code editors java".  You can then compile and run from the command line.  You might as well give it a try and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your needs a Raspberry Pi is perfectly adequate. IIRC the BlueJ Java IDE is part of the standard install.

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware of BlueJ Java and am now having a fun time playing with.  For others reading this, it appears under "Recommended Software"